# How to solve Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update records in MySQL table but I am running into the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=''
```

here is my query

```
$db->processQuery('UPDATE account_mids SET price_sheet_file = ? WHERE mid = ? AND price_sheet_file IS NULL', array($filename, $mid));
```

I have tried to add collate but did not work. This is what I have done

```
$db->processQuery('UPDATE account_mids SET price_sheet_file = ?  COLLATE utf8_general_ci    WHERE mid = ? COLLATE latin1_general_ci AND price_sheet_file IS NULL', array($filename, $mid));
```

but I got the following error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'latin1_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8''
```

Here is my show create table

```
CREATE TABLE `account_mids` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `program_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mid` char(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `stage` enum('Engaged','Pricing','Application Sent','Application Incomplete','No Sale','Pending Admin Approval','Admin Rejected','Admin Approved','Submit to PTC','Waiting PTC Decision','Approved','Declined','On Hold','Withdrawn','Cancelled','Change of Program') NOT NULL,
 `type` enum('Existing Business','New Business','New Prospect','Change of Ownership','Program Transfer') NOT NULL,
 `chapter_name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
 `account_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `agent_code` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'the 10th and 11th char in mid value plus 00 it will equal out 4 chars',
 `prin_code` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'the 7th 8th and 9th char in the mid plus 0 on the right which is equal to 4 chars',
 `price_sheet_file` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `closed_reason` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `closed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `approved_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `enrolled_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `training_requested_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `first_sale_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `speciality` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `mid` (`mid`),
 KEY `account_id` (`account_id`,`status`),
 CONSTRAINT `am_account_id` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`account_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=384010 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason why `mid` has different collation (`latin1`)?

Comment: @peterm because latin1 is faster that utf8. and the column mid is a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent half a day searching for answers to the dreaded "Illegal mix of collations" error. I found that some columns in my database were not specifically collated **utf8_unicode_ci**. It seems mysql implicitly collated these columns **utf8_general_ci**.

Specifically, running a 'SHOW CREATE TABLE table1' query outputted something like the following:

| table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`col1` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`col2` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`photo_id`,`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

Note the line **'col1' varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL** does not have a collation specified. I then ran the following query:

ALTER TABLE table1 CHANGE col1 col1 VARCHAR(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL;

This solved my "Illegal mix of collations" error. Hope this might help someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend viewing the table structure via Sequel Pro if possible since it's much easier to debug/compare. I created a new table and didn't use the CHARSET and COLLATE values used in previously created tables...

So this led to the error we are seeing above when running a query using both tables with different CHARSET and COLLATE values...

Compare the settings via the "Table Info" or the "Structure" tab and make sure the values for CHARSET AND COLLATE match.

[image]

To debug deeper run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and compare table CHARSET/COLLATE values and the table columns COLLATE values.

Example: `column1 varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`

If you can't use sequel pro review this mysql doc and run the alters...
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html