# how to fix mysql "Illegal mix of collations"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

How do you fix a problem like this? Is the error in the code the server or in the database?

I'm using Laravel 5.2. the data i'm using is imported through a json api and inserted into a database.

```
production.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' in /home/forge/fbjobb.XXX.se/envoyer/releases/20160809060739/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:335
```

Comment: Seems like a db design issue. (This typically happens when you compare two columns defined with different collations.)

Comment: Might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928647/how-to-solve-illegal-mix-of-collations-latin1-general-ci-implicit-error

Comment: Try opening your db with phpMyAdmin, adminer, or any other visual tool and check the collation of your tables. It seems some of them have "utf8_unicode_ci" encoding while others have default MySql encoding: "latin1_swedish_ci". Can be a result of import

Comment: @RuslanBes Exactly for some reason there where differances in my production and my stgage db. I copied the stage dp collitions to production and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You can workaround with php:

```
$t=mb_convert_encoding($t, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

This will remove wrong encoded charaters